# Why is the Zend DateTime Element not working?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

Why is my Zend DateTime element not working?

View:

```
 echo $this->formDateTime($form->get('initial_call_time'));
```

Form Class:

```
 $this->add(array(
     'name' => 'initial_call_time',
    'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\DateTime',
     'options' => array(
         'label' => 'Call Date Time',
        ),
     'attributes' => array(
     'min' => '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z',
     'max' => '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z',
     'step' => '1', // minutes; default step interval is 1 mint
```

)
     ));

Controller

```
$dateTimeLocal = new Element\DateTimeLocal('initial_call_time');
$dateTimeLocal
    ->setLabel('Appointment Date')
    ->setAttributes(array(
        'min'  => '2010-01-01T00:00:00',
        'max'  => '2020-01-01T00:00:00',
        'step' => '1', // minutes; default step interval is 1 min
    ))
    ->setOptions(array(
        'format' => 'Y-m-d\TH:i'
    ));

    $form = new InitialCallForm;
$form->add($dateTimeLocal);
```

Is there a good tutorial on this anywhere?  I tried to follow the instructions on the website but it does not seem to work.  Currently I get a blank form box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many browsers don't support the HTML element generated by this helper. Hence to answer your question you are likely testing on a non supported browser:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Comment: Take a look at DateTimeSelect, this uses traditional HTML select elements, however it uses the applications local by default so you may need to look at changing that during runtime. Otherwise use a good old JS widget.

link : http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/2.3/classes/Zend.Form.Element.DateTimeSelect.html